# Content based on url segment

Tags: channel-entries

I'm just learning EE and I have the following example url, http://mydomain.com/work/preview/clientname

where I want clientname to match a channel field I have setup ("client_name") and to pull in channel content only if it matches that channel field.

For example, http://mydomain.com/work/preview/google, would display channel content if the specified channel field "client_name" for a particular entry is "google".

I know how to use the following to pull in content from the channel "videos":

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="videos"}
    {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

...but how do I accomplish this for different url segments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will do the trick:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="videos" search:client_name="{segment_3}" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}
    {if no_results} {redirect="404"} {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```